# CakePHP 3 level join find method

Tags: cakephp, join

I have these tables in my database: 'products' belongs to a 'company', and 'company' has many 'company_addresses'. And I am building a search action in my controller which will return the products based on user's inputted company address. How can I get something like the followin?

```
SELECT *
FROM products
LEFT JOIN companies ON products.company_id = companies.id
LEFT JOIN company_addresses ON companies.id = company_addresses.company_id
WHERE company_addresses.address1 LIKE '%'.$this->data['Product']['keyword'].'%'
OR company_addresses.address2 LIKE '%'.$this->data['Product']['keyword'].'%'
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
$results = $this->Product->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            array('CompanyAddress.address1 LIKE' => '%'.$this->data['Product']['keyword'].'%'),
            array('CompanyAddress.address2 LIKE' => '%'.$this->data['Product']['keyword'].'%')
        )
    ),
    'order' =>    array(
        'Product.id' => 'ASC'
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Company' => array(
            'CompanyAddress' => array(
                'State',
                'City'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Nor this:

```
$results = $this->Product->find('all', array(
    'order' =>    array(
        'Product.id' => 'ASC'
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Company' => array(
            'CompanyAddress' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'OR' => array(
                        array('CompanyAddress.address1 LIKE' => '%'.$this->data['Product']['keyword'].'%'),
                        array('CompanyAddress.address2 LIKE' => '%'.$this->data['Product']['keyword'].'%')
                    )
                ),
                'State',
                'City'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best for you is to use the join of CakePHP.

Something like this:

```
    $this->Product->find('all', array(
                            'joins' => array(
                                array(
                                    'table' => 'companies',
                                    'alias' => 'Company',
                                    'type' => 'left',
                                    'conditions' => array(
                                        'Company.id = Product.company_id'
                                    ),
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'table' => 'companies_addresses',
                                    'alias' => 'CompaniesAddress',
                                    'type' => 'left',
                                    'conditions' => array(
                                        'CompaniesAdress.company_id = Company.id',
                                        'OR' => array(
                                            'CompanyAdress.address1 LIKE' => '%' . $this->data['Product']['keyword'] . '%', 
                                            'CompanyAdress.address2 LIKE' => '%' . $this->data['Product']['keyword'] . '%', 
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ));
```